# XA transaction in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, xa

I am trying to commit jms and database transaction in spring batch job. I was under assumption that spring batch transaction are xa transactions. But in my item writer even when jms transaction errored out database transaction is committing. Can any one pls help me if I am missing something. Do I need to third party libraries for XA in spring batch?

Comment: you need to define a JTA Transaction Manager that is XA (Atomikos is a good open source implementation) and ensure all your participants are XA compliant (eg you need an XA db driver and an XA JMS library). The spring batch in action book is a good reference and describes it in detail: https://livebook.manning.com/book/spring-batch-in-action/chapter-9/94

Comment: If you share the code we can check what is going wrong. Ideally when any exception is thrown it would roll out by each chunk if you are using chunk oriented processing. I am guessing you are not setting the JOB EXIT STATUS when the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually throwing exception intentionally to test transaction roll back. Now even without any jms transaction just a database transaction is committing even with exception thrown from the item writer.Below is the method in writer which is saving into DB. compEvent object is jpa repository injected into this class

```
private void writeCEs(Map<TrueEvent, List<Event>> agentMap)
        throws FailedCompensationException, Exception {
    for (Entry<TrueEvent, List<Event>> agent : agentMap.entrySet()) {
        agent.getValue().stream().forEach((ce) -> {
            compEvent.save(ce);
        });
        updateRecordFileStatus(agent.getKey());
        //postToAccounting(agent.getKey(), agent.getValue());
    }
    throw new Exception("Testing XA roolback.... ");
}
```

Below is my batch configuration

@EnableBatchProcessing
   @EnableTransactionManagement
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan({ "com.pm.*" })

public class TrueBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

```
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory steps;

@Autowired
EventReader reader;

@Autowired
private EventProcessor processor;

@Autowired
private EventWriter writer;

@Bean
protected Step step1(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor) {
    DefaultTransactionAttribute attribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
    attribute.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRED.value());
    attribute.setIsolationLevel(Isolation.DEFAULT.value());     
    attribute.setTimeout(30);

    return steps.get("step1").<List<TrueEvent>, Map<TrueUpEvent, List<Event>>>chunk(10).reader(reader)
            .processor(processor).writer(writer).transactionAttribute(attribute).build();
}

@Bean(name = "firstBatchJob")
public Job job(@Qualifier("step1") Step step1) {
    return jobs.get("firstBatchJob").start(step1).build();
}
```

}

Comment: I found kind of workaround. If I move persisting data into a separate service within its own transaction and with rollbackFor = Exception.class option it is rollback transactions. Looks like some spring proxy issue with transaction boundaries.